# Rails Query to show all posts that have no comments by current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, where-clause

I have an app that I need to see all the requests that have no quotes by the current user. I want to see Requests that have no quotes and requests that have quotes from other users.

For no quotes I have been using:

```
Request.includes(:quotes).where( quotes: { id: nil } ).order(created_at: :desc)
```

and for the Where Not query I was using:

```
Requests.joins(:quotes).where.not(quotes: { service_center_id: current_service_center.id })
```

This works with one quote. If I quote on a Request, the Request is no longer in the list, but as soon as someone else quotes it comes back into my list. It as if the query sees the other quotes are not by me so if shows the request, even though I have also quoted.

Here is a link to a Thoughtbot blog on where not that inspired me to look into models. Towards the bottom he does the same query. I have emailed the author but not reply yet.
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activerecords-wherenot

Here are my models:

**User**:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

validates :first_name,  presence: true  
alidates :last_name,   presence: true  
validates :zipcode,     presence: true  


has_many :autos  
has_many :requests  
has_many :quotes, through: :requests  
has_many :appointments, through: :quotes
```

**Request**:

```
belongs_to :user  
belongs_to :auto  
has_many :quotes, dependent: :destroy  
has_many :appointments, through: :quotes  

validates :service, presence: true  

serialize :service

validates_associated :quotes
```

**Quote**:

```
belongs_to :request  
belongs_to :service_center
```

**Service_center**:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable  

has_many :quotes  
has_many :requests, through: :quotes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve your three goals.

Requests with no quotes:

```
Request.includes(:quotes).where( quotes: { id: nil } ).order(created_at: :desc)
```

Requests with quotes from other service centers:

```
Requests.joins(:quotes).where.not(quotes: { service_center_id: current_service_center.id })
```

Here is the answer to your question:

Requests with no quotes from your service center:

```
Request.where.not(
  id: Request.joins(:quotes)
        .where(quotes: { service_center_id: current_service_center.id })
        .select(:id) 
)
```

This is somewhat janky, but it should work.  The subquery gets all of the requests that have a quote from the current service center.  The outer query returns all of the requests that are not in the first list.  It should still run fast with one query in the database.

Another solution which will yield the same result is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
Request.joins(:quotes).where(
  Quote
    .where('requests.id = quotes.request_id')
    .where('quotes.service_center_id = ? ', current_service_center.id)
    .exists.not
)
```

This will result in a `NOT EXISTS` subquery in SQL.  It should result in roughly the same performance as the other query.  I suppose it is just a matter of preference.

Comment: Checking! Thanks for the prompt response and reformat of my question. As the current.service_center gets more and more quotes that will become a heavy search? or maybe pulling just the id's from quotes isn't too bad. it's not like we are pulling all the data.

Comment: This query will be fairly performant even with a large number of quotes because it is not sending the quote ids to Rails.  If you look at the `sql` or `.explain`, it is a fairly fast query.  All the the work is happening in the database.  It is the equivalent of writing a query with a `NOT EXISTS ()` subquery in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, it gave the same results as the previous one. If Request has multiple Quotes it does not exclude it from the results. if say request 115 has 3 quotes and one of those is from current _service_center, request 115 actually still shows up.

Comment: I updated the answer.  Took a completely different approach.

Comment: Tom, I'm doing some checking but I think you did it. It also takes care of the nil query. I also want to say going right to the Request.where.not prior to the joins is amazing! I think that there solved the duplicate Requests on multiple quotes. you sir are the MVP. My vote is coming after some Testing.

Comment: Tom it worked great! Thank you so much. I ran with the Request.where.not() and it has worked great! I tried up check the answer but as I am a newbie it wont let me.